# Merging the lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, and I want to merge them for ListPlot3D.

First, I made a list of `{x,y}` points for `lx=0.3; ly=0.3; dx=0.1; dy=0.1`

```
grid = Table[{{i, j}}, {i, 0, lx, dx}, {j, 0, ly, dy}]

(* {{{{0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.1}}, {{0., 0.2}}, {{0., 0.3}}}, {{{0.1, 0.}},
{{0.1, 0.1}}, {{0.1, 0.2}}, {{0.1, 0.3}}}, {{{0.2, 0.}}, {{0.2, 0.1}},
{{0.2, 0.2}}, {{0.2, 0.3}}}, {{{0.3, 0.}}, {{0.3, 0.1}}, {{0.3, 0.2}}, {{0.3, 0.3}}}}
 *)
```

The values are given

```
v={113.864, 99.4164, 90.5971, 85.1589, 72.8399, 85.7906, 68.1644, 58.7077, 50.1663, 
   72.0986, 52.0997, 42.4192, 37.144, 66.1972, 44.6466, 34.9181}
```

How can I merge two lists and get `new={0, 0, 113.864}, {0, 0.1, 99.4164}...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Join[
  Flatten[grid, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}],
  Partition[v, {1}],
  2
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0) with appended zeros as placeholders
for replacement

```
SubsetMap[v &, Append[0] /@ Flatten[grid, 2], {All, -1}];

ListPlot3D[%]
```

[image]